# How to use numpy with temporally sensitive data?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a loop that I want to convert to vectorized code using numpy.

If this loop contains some calculation that depends on the previous iteration of itself, can I use numpy here?

For eg. but not limitted to:

```
v=[]
v.append(1)
for i in range(n):
    v.append(v[i]+np.random.rand(10, size=1))
    if(v[i]-v[i-1]<5)"
       break
```

Comment: Not really, and you don't want to. NumPy provides a `@vectorize` decorator, but it's not for performance, it's for convenience.
However, you could use [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), or a C/C++ extension and make this very efficient. I suggest the former, with a pre-allocated array and then assign to the index. Using Numba should dramatically increase the performance of this code.

Comment: Also, you have a logic error in your code: `if(v[i]-v[i-1]<5)"` will evaluate to `if(v[0]-v[-1]<5)"` on the first loop. I believe you mean `if(v[i+1]-v[i]<5)"`.

Comment: Sometimes problems like this can use `cumsum` or other `ufunc` with `accumulate`,  Otherwise `vectorize` in numpy means calculate all values 'at-once', in parallel,  not sequentially.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, quite apart from speed, `np.vectorize` won't work.  It passes scalar values to the function.  There's no way to write a function that would use previously calculated values.